# Derivative of function for matrices

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

I am trying to understand how to proceed with this equation, in order to find derivatives and form matrix later on:

[image]

What does $A$ and $x^T$ represent here for matrix or vectors?
I have to differentiate with respect to $A$ and $x$, I suppose. But how to proceed, any suggestions?

Comment: $A$ represents a matrix; $x$ represents a (column) vector, and $x^T$ represents $x$ transpose (i.e. its row vector). $A$ is a constant, and $x$ is the variable you must differentiate w.r.t to

Comment: @FShrike you mean, differentiate with respect to T?

Comment: I mean differentiate with respect to $x$! $x$ is a variable in $\Bbb R^n$, whereas $T$ is simply a notation for the transpose